# How to copy all files from one ftp folder to sftp folder by changing the file names

Tags: java

In java, how can I copy all files from one ftp folder to sftp folder? Also, how can I change all the file names (suffix with dateformats) and delete/archive them in the source.

Could you get me some samples please.

Answer (score 0):

[JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is one of the best SFTP libraries I've seen for Java. The have good [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) as well...particularly this [example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java).